# Passing a parameter having a data type money in SP using VBA

Tags: ms-access

I have a field in a employee table named salary. The salary field data type is money.
Now in Gui I want to pass the salary in the store procedure that correspond to the data type of the salary
Here is my sample code to pass the value of the salary by creating a parameter.

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("Salary", what should be the data type that I will be using?, adParamInput, 20, mstrMaximumADBCoverAmount)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm

Comment: You need more details than just saying MS-ACCESS and VBA. What data interface are you wanting to use? What database is the data stored in?

Answer (score 1):

If prm is an ADO parameter, and Salary is a SQL Server money type field, use adCurrency as the ADO parameter type.

More information: [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=97) and [ADO DataTypeEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms806221.aspx)